# Asp.Net core: Get required service via depedency injection in non-controller libraries. E.g. C# Common library

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

As I am using default dependency inject functionality of Asp.net core, it works great by resolving dependency via Constructor.

E.g.

**Registration:**

```
public static void AddServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationRoot configuration)
{
    services.AddScoped<ICookieManager, CookieManager>();
}
```

**Access via constructor:**

```
protected ICookieManager CookieManager { get; set; }

public HomeController(ICookieManager cookieManager)
{
    this.CookieManager = cookieManager;
}
```

**The above code works great!**

Now, I have a library called `Library.Common` where I have some common functionality written which can be used by different project.

**In my common library code, how would I resolve the dependency without constructor**?

I want something like this:

```
public void CalculateOrder()
{
    var cookieManager = ServiceLocator.Instance.GetService<ICookieManager>();
}
```

Would anybody help me to find out how would I resolve the dependency without constructor in Asp.net core? Like resolving in common library, in static methods without constructor.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't do it. Service Locator pattern beats the idea of having an IoC/DI container in the first place. Just use Constructor injection and you are good to go. You can use factories which abstract it. The service locator will bite you really hard when you try accessing scoped resources. Service locator is an antipattern, making testing very complicated and error prone

Comment: Since you state that you don't have a constructor, is it possible to just pass the `ICookieManager` into the `CalculateOrder` method as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Leave it as a constructor injected dependency. If your common library is to be used across multiple projects where DI is used it will work fine (assuming you configure the DI container correctly). If DI is not used you can simply construct an instance of an ICookieManager implementation and pass it into the constructor as an argument.

You could also consider using property injection for the dependency, although this would be most suitable where your method, CalculateOrder(), can still provide some functional value without the ICookieManager dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answer is correct in saying that it's probably better for a multitude of reasons to use constructor DI. If this is a new project inside .NET Core, you are better off doing things right from the start.

That being said, if you have an extreme need for using ServiceLocator or you are migrating a project across and you don't want to have to redo everything in one go to use constructor DI, you can simply create a static ServiceLocator class that uses .NET Core's injectable DI.

An example of this is here : https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/05/06/servicelocator-shim-for-net-core/ Where you just create a static class that simply runs the "GetService" method from .NET Core's Service Collection.